# What is the right way to host different Django apps as nginx locations

Tags: nginx, gunicorn

I have a static website (www.example.com) and a Django app (example.com/app1) running on a single server machine (machine 1).

Both the website and the app are served using nginx. I am using gunicorn to serve the Django app.

The nginx configuration on machine 1 looks like this:

```
upstream gunicorn {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000; # gunicorn serving App1
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

root /var/www/example;  

index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /;
}

# Django media and static files
location /media  {
    alias /var/www/media;
    }

location /static {
    alias /var/www/static;
    }

# gunicorn App1
location /app1 {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /app1;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://gunicorn;
}

location /app2 {
    # This App2 is served on a different machine (machine 2).
    # Not yet implemented
}
}
```

I am now trying to get a second app running (example.com/app2) as a second location on a second machine (machine 2). Is it necessary to have another nginx running on machine 2 to get this to work? Or can i just forward to gunicorn on machine 2? I already tried both using

```
upstream gunicornMachine2 {
    server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 # IP of second machine or port 8000 for gunicorn
}
```

and

```
location /app2 {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /app2;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://gunicornMachine2;
}
```

This does provide a 502 Bad Gateway.
What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: Nginx is not needed on server #2. However, when using without Nginx, please be sure to open the gunicorn port for server #1.

Comment: @Pothi According to netstat gunicorn is listening on tcp 127.0.0.1:8000. However, using the machines internal-network IP address I am not able to access the app from a client inside the network. Seems I need to research some more on how this works. Thanks for pointing me into the right direction.

Comment: @Pothi Why do I need to open the port on server #1?

Comment: Please re-read my comment. I said "for server #1". Not "on server #1".

Comment: Ok, just to get this right: Port 80 for standard web traffic is open on server #1. This is also how requests for server #2 will enter the internal network. server #1 will then connect to server #2 on port 8000 for getting the data from gunicorn. This is an internal connection. Server #2 is listening on port 8000 as far as netstat is concerned. What exactly is closed here and how do I need to open it?